# Python LinkedList Garbage Collector

Tags: python, garbage-collection

My question is, will the object **Node(3)** still be in RAM memory once we reach the end of **remove()** function ? If no, when is it deleted from RAM memory ?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def add(self, data):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Node(data)
        else:
            curr_node = self.head
            while (curr_node.next):
                curr_node = curr_node.next
            curr_node.next = Node(data)

    def remove(self, data):
        if self.head is not None:
            if self.head.data == data:
                self.head = self.head.next
            else:
                curr_node = self.head
                while curr_node.next is not None:
                    if curr_node.next.data == data:
                        curr_node.next = curr_node.next.next
                        break
                    curr_node = curr_node.next

l = LinkedList()
l.add(2)
l.add(3)
l.add(4)
l.remove(3)

# program going on ...
```

Comment: After `remove(3)` the node seems to be unreachable (if there isn't another reference to it somewhere else). If an object is unreachable it will be freed at some unspecified time in the future or not at all (if process terminates, the OS frees memory). Python specification isn't more precise about that. Calling `gc.collect()` usually frees unreachable objects immediately.

Comment: Note that the reason your OS might not free it immediately is because it requires ressources to delete them but, in general, it is nearly instantaneous. You usually don't need to worry about the `gc`.

Comment: The exact behavior of garbage collection depends on the Python implementation. CPython behaves very differently in these kinds of situations than PyPy or Jython does, for example.